# How do I remove Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

My system runs Vista, I have installed 12.04 to run in parrallel.
I should be able to choose to run VISTA or UBUNTU but it will not let me.
None of my Windows programs will load from disc. All I can get is progs from the internet.
I can get to my youtube account but it will not play the sound.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: We can only deal with one problem at a time. We can't answer your first or second questions without more information, like how you installed Ubuntu, how you tried loading your Windows applications (they don't run natively in Ubuntu you know) and I'm not sure we can answer your sound question either, without more info. How about a screenshot of `alsamixer`? Or you can just follow the link in the comment above and remove Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You should have never expected an OS to be able to run programs coded with an entirely different OS's API flawlessly, if at all. That is not how computers work. If you are having problems accessing Windows from system boot then you probably need to change your BIOS settings. Next time try being more mature as well. It's not Ubuntu's fault that you didn't know what you were getting yourself into.